# how to auto click element in webbrowser? VB

Tags: visual-studio

i need auto click some element on page load.

web:

https://faucet.raiblockscommunity.net/form.php

this is the source:

```
<div class="cookieinfo-close" style="float: right; display: block; padding: 5px 8px; min-width: 100px; margin-left: 5px; border-radius: 5px; cursor: pointer; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(241, 214, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; text-align: center;">Got it!</div>
```

this is my VB code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication16
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

I need to automatically click on the element when the page is loaded on the webbrowser, without pressing any button

Comment: _this is my VB code:_ - what sorcery is this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by different ways. One of them is to integrate **Selenium** and use fire path/firebug to inspect the element, to get the respective id and then you can use following code,

```
WebDriver test_driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.findElement(By.id("element id"))
```

You can do this in different ways within **Selenium** . Refer the link: https://loadfocus.com/blog/2013/09/05/how-to-locate-web-elements-with-selenium-webdriver/